# iPhone Cocos2d: trying to render a sprite but i am only seeing a white rectangle

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'am trying to make the following code work but I only see white rectangles when rendering them :S;

```
CCSprite *tempSprite = [[CCSprite spriteWithTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"Icon.png"]] retain];

TapCircle *tapObject = [[TapCircle alloc] initWithSprite:tempSprite];
```

The TapCircle class is a subclass of TapElement which in turn is a subclass of CCNode. 
The initWithSprite code in TapCircle:

```
- (id) initWithSprite:(CCSprite*)tex {

    if ((self = [super init]) == nil) return nil;

    [self addChild:tex];

    return self;
}
```

The TapCircle object is then added to a parent CCNode which in turn is added to the layer being rendered. I have tested creating the tempsprite in another projekt where I added it directly to the layer and it worked... So must be some kind of parent-child-problem?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the Icon.png as project resource?  Also, shouldn't you be deriving from CCSprite?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a start I think you've got the debug setting `CC_SPRITE_DEBUG_DRAW` or `CC_SPRITEBATCHNODE_DEBUG_DRAW` defined in ccConfig.h.  This will put a white rectangle around your sprites.